# Securely running an apache container on k8s

Tags: apache, kubernetes

I've built a docker image based on [httpd:2.4](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). In my k8s deployment I've defined the following `securityContext`:

```
securityContext:
  privileged: false
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 431
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

When I apply the deployment without this `securityContext` everything works fine, the server starts up correctly, etc. However when I add in the above `securityContext` my pod has the status `CrashLoopBackOff` and I get the following from `$ kubectl logs...`

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

From searching around online I've found that this is because apache needs to be root in order to run, so running as non-root will fail.

I've also found that `httpd.conf` has the following

```
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Which seems to suggest that if I don't use `runAsNonRoot` or `runAsUser` in `securityContext` it should automatically switch to whichever user I specify in `httpd.conf`. In my case I created a user/group `swuser` and edited `httpd.conf` accordingly. However when I run the image locally with `docker run -p 5000:80 my-registry/my-image:1.0.12-alpha` and then run `docker exec -it my-container whoami` it prints `root`.

So my question is, what can I do to run my container safely as non-root in k8s (and be sure it is non-root)

Comment: Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Run the apache on a port greater than 1024.

Ports below 1024 are privileged ports only available to the root user.

As you will have some ingress load balancer before that, it shouldn't matter :-)

Comment: I tried this (changing `Listen 80` to `Listen 8000` in `httpd.conf`. Is there more?), and while the server seems to start up successfully, I'm having trouble accessing the service at what should be the appropriate url. My k8s deployment `containerPort` and service `targetPort` are both 8000. The service `port` itself is 8080, and in my ingress I list `servicePort` as 8080 as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you directly connect to the pod on that port? What is shown in `kubectl describe pod <pod>`, is it the expected port? Seems like something with the ingress is wrong. Maybe you fixed it while I was camping?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in your Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i "s/Listen 80/Listen ${PORT:-8080}/g" /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

This command is a Dockerfile instruction that runs a sed command to replace the default Listen 80 configuration in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file with a specified port number. Here's a breakdown of the command:

RUN is a Dockerfile instruction that allows you to run commands inside the container during the build process.

sed is a command-line utility that is used to edit files in-place using regular expressions.

-i flag tells sed to modify the file in-place, meaning the original file will be overwritten with the changes.

"s/Listen 80/Listen ${PORT:-8080}/g" is a regular expression used by sed to find and replace the Listen 80 string with the value of the ${PORT} environment variable or the default value 8080 if ${PORT} is not set.

/etc/apache2/ports.conf is the path to the file to be edited by sed.

The command can be interpreted as follows: "During the Docker image build process, replace the default Apache web server port Listen 80 with the port number specified in the ${PORT} environment variable. If ${PORT} is not set, use the default port number 8080. This is done by running the sed command to edit the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file."

This command is commonly used in Dockerfiles for web applications that run on a specific port, allowing the user to define the port number during runtime via an environment variable.

You can see and edit your command with [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed%20-i%20%22s%2FListen%2080%2FListen%20%24%7BPORT%3A-8080%7D%2Fg%22%20%2Fetc%2Fapache2%2Fports.conf)

[Command details on explaishell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBQ0c.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).